# Advice for reference the same image for several nodes?

Tags: nodes, media

I need to show the same image for a several nodes. I have uploaded the image to the server. But, I am not sure how to accomplish or reference this using the image field. Do you have any experience that you can share it? or any other way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the easiest was to do the following steps:

1. In content/media add the picture.
2. In your content type create a field type **File**. Save your content type.
3. When you add your new content, in your new field, use select media and choose the file that just upload it.

Note: If you delete the new content and there is no other content that reference that picture or file, the file will be deleted and you need to upload it again.

I created my content by using web services. So, I needed to do this programatically. The only I needed was the fid.

In my case I need to use services to create the content type, after testing you need the following and to tell if it should be displayed or not. This is the code in case anyone feels it is useful.

$node->field_file_name_field ['und'][0]['fid']='fid number';
$node->field_file_name_field['und'][0]['display']='1';

If you feel there is a better way or another way to do this. It be great to hear it.