# Is there module that allows linking or embedding attachments or images from other nodes?

Tags: nodes, navigation

I need a module that allows me to link or embed attachments and images from other nodes, using a filter syntax like [moduletag:node-id:filename], [moduletag:node-id:attachment_index], [moduletag:node-id:image_index].

It will be especially helpful on nodes which exist for attaching images to, so that I can reference individual images on that node if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use the **Media** module (https://www.drupal.org/project/media)...

**Alternative 1:**

I have no experience with this module, but **FileField Sources** (https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) could solve your problem, including:

- Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
- Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
- Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)
- Paste a file directly from the clipboard (Drupal 7 only)
- Select existing files through the IMCE file browser

**Alternative 2**

Another possibility is described here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53971/36708

Comment: I am not concerned with adding media, I want to display media added to one node in a different node, using a simple filter.